# How to use Try and Try[Option[T]] in for comprehension?

Tags: scala

I have one function that returns Try[Option[T]] and another function that accepts T as input argument and returns Try[Boolean].
Is this possible to combine them in for comprehension?
May be with cat's OptionT?
I tried to do this like this without luck:

```
    val result =
      for{
      u <- OptionT(function1)
      res <- function2(u)
    } yield res
```

Comment: can you update with your two functions?

Comment: What would you like the result to be if `function1` return `Success(None)`? In other words, what would you want the type of `result` to be?

Comment: @TzachZohar  I'd like result type to be Try[Option[Boolean]]

Comment: read about monad transformers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like cats' [`sequence`](http://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Traverse.html#sequence[G[_],A](fga:F[G[A]])(implicitevidence$2:cats.Applicative[G]):G[F[A]]) can help here - it allows "swapping" the `Try` and the `Option` (that's basically what you need to do, so that the `Try[Boolean]` result of `function2` can wrap around the `Option` and not the other way around):

```
def solution[T](function1: => Try[Option[T]], function2: T => Try[Boolean]): Try[Option[Boolean]] = {
  import cats.implicits._
  for {
    a <- function1
    b <- a.map(function2).sequence[Try, Boolean]
  } yield b

}

println(solution[String](Success(Some("s")), s => Success(true))) // Success(Some(true))
println(solution[String](Success(Some("s")), s => Failure(new RuntimeException))) // Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException)
println(solution[String](Success(None), s => ???)) // Success(None)
println(solution[String](Failure(new RuntimeException), s => ???)) // Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this using `OptionT` monad transformer from the cats library. You can use `OptionT.liftF` method to convert `Try[T]` to `OptionT[Try, T]`:

```
def solution[T](
  function1: => Try[Option[T]], 
  function2: T => Try[Boolean]
): Try[Option[Boolean]] = (
  for {
    r1 <- OptionT(function1)
    r2 <- OptionT.liftF(function2(r1))
  } yield r2
).value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for {
    optionT <- tryOptionT()
    t <- optionT
    result <- tryBoolean(t)
} yield result
```